# Reference to a directory?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a program in C# WPF that allows the user to manually input a directory in a textbox so that the program will retrieve and list the files in the specified directory into another textbox.

My problem is that I don't know how to assign the value from a textbox to the directory path.

I'm able to specify the directory manually in the code however I'm not sure how to assign the directory path from a textbox...

Any ideas?

My code when a button is clicked is as follows:

```
            // Makes a reference to a directory.
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(textbox.Text);
```

That should work.